# How to convert string to double in swift

Tags: swift

value is taken from a dictionary of Any that may contain strings

```
if value is String {
    total += Double(value)    
}
```

this code gives the error "cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type '(Any)'"

```
if let item = value as? String {
    total += Double(item)
}
```

this code gives the error "value of optional type 'Double?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"

Comment: You just need to optional bind `Double(item)` as well. `if let item = value as? String, let itemValue = Double(item) {
    total += itemValue
}`

Comment: You are checking with the `if let` that `value` is a String, that's good. But nothing can assure that `Double(item)` is valid. Sample test: `let d1 = Double("3"); let d2 = Double("abc")`, `d2` is nil.

Comment: You need do also do an `if let` for it: `if let item = value as? String { if let doubleValue = Double(item) { total += doubleValue } }`, which can be written also as `if let item = value as? String, let doubleValue = Double(item) { total += doubleValue}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Value of optional type 'Double?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

This error appears because you are trying to add an optional value to `total`.

`Double(item)` produces an optional result so you can add it in **if-let** chain.

```
    if let item = value as? String, let doubleVal = Double(item) {
        total += doubleVal
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Double(fromString)` is a failable initializer, the result can be nil thus it returns an optional `Double?`

You can use Swift's Nil-Coalescing Operator:

```
if let item = value as? String {
    total += Double(item) ?? 0
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to not add anything at all in case a `Double` value is not found?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri What is wrong about adding zero to a total?

Comment: @LeoDabus unnecessary and redundant?

Answer (score 1):

Forecasting any Value may sometimes give fatal error when the value may be null. So it is a good practise to give default value using ??

Answer (score 0):

**Convert Swift String to Double**

*Use Double, Float, CGFloat to convert floating-point values (real numbers).*

```
let lessPrecisePI = Float("3.14")
let morePrecisePI = Double("3.1415926536")
let width = CGFloat(Double("200.0")!)
```

**Convert Swift String to Int**
*Use Int and the variants like Int32, UInt64, etc. to convert integer values.*

```
let wholeNumber = Int("27")
let smallInt = Int16("34")
let largeInt = Int64("39384")
```

Check this blog for more details [supereasyapps.com](https://supereasyapps.com/blog/2015/9/28/how-to-convert-strings-into-double-and-float-values-using-swift-2)